# Cannot make additional vnc viewer (Kind of Xvnc failed, possibly because the font path.... matter)

Tags: vncserver, vnc-viewer

From a week ago, I cannot make additional vnc viewer.
I found many people already have this kind of error, but specifically, they were a little different.

I found one solution for one similar case, that is

```
yum update
yum install pixman pixman=devel libXfont
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.

The following is my error log.

Does anybody have how to solve this problem and could you explain the meaning of each line?

```
WARNING: The first attempt to start Xvnc failed, possibly because the font
catalog is not properly configured.  Attempting to determine an appropriate
font path for this system and restart Xvnc using that font path ...
Could not start Xvnc.

_XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/servername:3
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for inet6
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
_XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/servername:3
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for inet6
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and explain in detail what you have done, what your goals are, which commands you have executed, and what fails. The error is from `Xvnc`, a VNC **server**, but you say you want to run a VNC **viewer** (client), and an "additional" one. So is one VNC viewer already running correctly?

Comment: I installed the VNC on the server and the users have created their accounts and used their own VNC viewer without any problems (as you said, one VNC viewer is already running correctly).

Only one person failed to create her vnc viewer.

However, from about a week ago, all users cannot make their additional VNC viewer.

Whenever we tried to type 'vncserver -geometry 1920x1080', the error message I mentioned above came out. Even though I made a new user's account, the same problem occurs. I've tried the solution from people with similar problems, but our problem has not been solved yet.

Comment: So, I want to ask anybody who knows how to solve that problem, and what caused the error.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused. You are saying that people try to create "additional viewers" by running the command "vncserver"? But as the name "vncserver" implies, this starts a VNC **server**. What command are the people using to start the viewers? (A "VNC server" is a program that "VNC viewers" can connect to. A "VNC viewer" is a program that opens a window, and displays the content of the VNC server it connects to. You can point two different viewers to the same VNC server, if you configure the server correctly. You don't need to start a new server for each viewer.).

Comment: I'm sorry to make you confused. Umm.. one VNC server for one account, but we want to get a new display number (i.e. (host address):##  
For example, after typing 'vncserver -geometry 1920x1080' 
and if  I succeed,

the following message comes up 'New 'host address:29 'desktop is host address:29'
and the number 29 is my new VNC viewer display number to connect to the server.'
And now I'm failed to get that display number.
Could it be explained?
(I work on CentOS 7.)

Comment: Wait. You are starting one VNC server for each account? How many accounts do you have? (And what the error message says is "server already running", so you are trying to start a server (and not a viewer) on a display number that's already in use.) Also, VNC servers use quite a bit of memory, so what you are doing will eventually make the computer really really slow... I'd suggest to use a different approach for whatever it is you are trying to achieve with this setup.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the late comment. 
'How many accounts do you have?' - I have only one account. VNC server is installed on the lab server computer. Our lab members access to the server computer via VNC viewer. 
Fortunately, after reboot the server computer, I solved that problem. Now it works well, but still I do not know what caused that matter. Anyway, thank you for your kind reply, again. I'll keep your advice in mind!